# Is it possible to make the fields of a derived class also be derived?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, field

Say I have a couple classes;

```
public class A {
    public int value;

    public A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public B(int value) : base(value) { }
}

public class Base {
    public A someobject;

    public Base(A someobject)
    {
        this.someobject = someobject;
    }
}
```

If I wanted to derive from class `Base`, I could write this;

```
public class Derived : Base {
    public Derived(A someobject) : base(someobject) { }
}
```

But is it possible to change the datatype of the `someobject` field to be a derived subclass, like in this example?

```
public class Derived : Base {
    public B someobject;

    public Derived(B someobject) : base(someobject) { }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't change the data type of the `someobject` field. You are currently hiding the base field and declaring a new one in `Derived`. Having said that, your code compiles and works apart from the warning generated by the field-hiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible - it would be dangerous to do so. Just a note: you're currently using *fields*, not *properties*, which do not allow you to override them at all (though you *can* hide the base field). However, even with properties, you still cannot change the return type of the property when overriding.

Consider the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Base myThing = new Derived();
    //We view it as a Base object, so we can assign any Animal to MyAnimal
    myThing.MyAnimal = new Cat();

    //Now let's cast it back to Derived
    Derived myCastThing = (Derived)myThing;
    myCastThing.MyAnimal; //We expect a Dog, but we get a Cat?
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual Animal MyAnimal { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public override Dog MyAnimal { get; set; }
}
public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

You can achieve what you want using generics, however:

```
public class Base<TAnimalType> where TAnimalType : Animal
{
    public virtual TAnimalType MyAnimal { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base<Dog>
{
    public override Dog MyAnimal { get; set; }
}
```